Jacoco coverage for openliberty integration tests
We have integration tests in our app in a self contained module within the project. Similar to the ones in this openliberty tutorial https://openliberty.io/guides/rest-intro.html#testing-the-service
These are run in the build by maven failsafe plugin.
Is there a way we could generate a jacoco test coverage for these tests in our build?
Note: Jacoco already produces coverage for our unit tests but we also want to create coverage report for these openliberty integration tests.

I will let you know how I just did it in maven, and hopefully, it helps you.
I have a multi-module maven project that contains the modules A, B, C under the parent module, with A being an API, B being the client, and C being the integration tests between them.
Module declaration in parent-pom:
   <modules>
        <module>A-API</module>
        <module>B-CLIENT</module>
        <module>C-INTEGRATION-TESTS</module>
    </modules>

In the parent pom.xml I added:
   <modules>
        <module>A-API</module>
        <module>B-CLIENT</module>
        <module>C-INTEGRATION-TESTS</module>
        <module>D-COVERAGE-REPORT</module>
    </modules>

Then I added the following as plugin to the parent pom:
           <plugin>
               <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
               <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
               <version>${jacoco.maven.plugin.version}</version>
               <executions>
                   <execution>
                       <id>prepare-agent</id>
                       <goals>
                           <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                       </goals>
                   </execution>
                 </executions>
           </plugin>

In the pom of module D, that contains the aggregate report generation I added:
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${jacoco.maven.plugin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>verify</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>report-aggregate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <dataFileIncludes>
                                <dataFileInclude>**/jacoco.exec</dataFileInclude>
                            </dataFileIncludes>
                            <outputDirectory>
                                ${project.reporting.outputDirectory}/jacoco-aggregate
                            </outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

And as dependencies I added the different modules:
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.company</groupId>
            <artifactId>api</artifactId> <!--this is module A-->
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.company</groupId>
            <artifactId>client</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version> <!--this is module B-->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.company</groupId>
            <artifactId>integration-tests</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version> <!--this is module C-->
        </dependency>
      </dependencies>

In my integration test module, I had modules A and B already declared as dependencies. There is no main src. All the integration tests are in the src/test. This caused JaCoCo to say: No class files specified. Currently, JaCoCo doesn't seem to work with external dependencies for code coverage. See the outstanding ticket here: https://github.com/jacoco/jacoco/issues/404
I added the following plugin:
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${org.codehaus.mojo.build-helper-maven-plugin.version}</version>
                <executions>
<execution>
                        <id>add-main-source</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>add-source</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sources>
                                <source>${project.parent.basedir}/api/src/main</source> <!--this refers to the src of your module A-->
                                <source>${project.parent.basedir}/client/src/main</source> <!--this refers to the src of your module B-->
                            </sources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>

When you run maven now you should see the integration test module being included including the code coverage for each of the classes of the separate modules.
What this doesn't do is merge the results of the integration tests with the results of the unit tests.

Hi Frank, Thanks for your detailed reply. Are your integration tests using openliberty similar to example provided?
